# Verificar se o número é positivo, negativo ou zero

Tags: python

Olá.
Estou estudando e aprendendo Python, e no momento preciso faz um código que leia uma coluna de um determinado arquivo onde os valores variam entre positivos, negativos e zero, e que escreva um arquivo de saída (.txt) onde a resposta seja -1 para negativos, 0 para os nulos e 1 para positivos.

Um exemplo de valores do arquivo:

```
   0; 0.0000
   1;-0.5921
   2;-0.3673
   3; 0.0000
   4; 0.0235
   5; 0.1685
```

O arquivo de saída seria algo parecido com isso:

```
   0; 0
   1; -1
   2; -1
   3; 0
   4; 1
   5; 1
```

O código que eu escrevi até o momento é:

```
arquivo = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')
i = 0

for linha in arquivo:
    campo = linha.split(';')
    vaz = float(campo[1])
    i = i+1
    fou = open('res.id.txt','wt')
pass
def vazdiff():
    if vaz < 0:
        if vaz == 0:
            vazdiff = 0
        else:
            vazdiff = 1 
    else:
        vazdiff = -1
    return vazdiff
pass
fou.write('{};{}'.format(i,vazdiff()))
fou.close
```

Porém estou tendo dificuldades pra terminar ele e fazer com que o arquivo de saída saia correto, e também pra deixar ele o mais compacto possível.

Qualquer ajuda e explicação sobre o código será bem-vinda, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se atente:

- Neste seu código, existem esses dois `pass`, que efetivamente não estão fazendo nada;
- A linha `fou.write('{};{}'.format(i,vazdiff()))` não está dentro de um `for`, por isso grava apenas 1 elemento no novo txt;
- O metodo `vazdiff()`, da forma que está feito, calcula o resultado apenas do último `vaz` encontrado;
- Além disso, a lógica dentro dele está errada. Veja que o código nunca vai entrar em `if vaz == 0:`, pois este `if` está dentro de `if vaz < 0:`. Ou seja, se `vaz`é menor do que 0, ele não pode ser == 0
- Use `\n` para quebrar a linha dentro do novo txt;
- Crie uma lista para guardar os resultados.

Tente algo parecido com isso:

```
arquivo = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')
lista = []

# Leia o arquivo
for linha in arquivo:
    campo = linha.split(';')
    #print(campo)
    vaz = float(campo[1])
    print(vaz)
    # Salve os dados na lista
    if vaz < 0:
        lista.append("-1")
    elif vaz == 0:
        lista.append("0")
    elif vaz > 0:
        lista.append("1")
arquivo.close()
print(lista)

fou = open('res.id.txt','wt')
i = 0
#Percorra a lista e salve o resultado em outro arquivo
for l in lista:
    fou.write('{}; {}\n'.format(i,l))
    i+=1
fou.close()
```

Se voce quiser utilizar o metodo `vazdiff()`, passe um parâmetro a ele:

```
arquivo = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')
lista = []

def vazdiff(vaz):
    if vaz < 0:
        lista.append("-1")
    elif vaz == 0:
        lista.append("0")
    elif vaz > 0:
        lista.append("1")

# Leia o arquivo
for linha in arquivo:
    campo = linha.split(';')
    #print(campo)
    vaz = float(campo[1])
    print(vaz)
    # Chame o metodo, passando o parametro
    vazdiff(vaz)

arquivo.close()
print(lista)

fou = open('res.id.txt','wt')
i = 0
#Percorra a lista e salve o resultado em outro arquivo
for l in lista:
    fou.write('{}; {}\n'.format(i,l))
    i+=1
fou.close()
```